# pjsua：Err=70018 (gethostbyname() has returned error (PJ_ERESOLVE))

Tags: gethostbyname

the pjsua project is configured in linux(centos)，the follows are my codes.Please help me,I have checked more about this problem ,but nothing useful about pjsua testing in linux.

> [root@hy bin]# ls pjsua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu  PJSYSTEST.TXT 
>   pjsystest-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu  reg.cfg  samples [root@hy bin]#
>   ./pjsua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --config-file reg.cfg

**after this,the error is coming：**

> 02:43:37.421  sip_resolve.c  ...Failed to resolve 'xxxxxxx(sip
>   address）'. Err=70018 (gethostbyname() has returned error
>   (PJ_ERESOLVE))
>
> 02:43:37.421   tsx0x2342998  ...Failed to send Request msg
>   REGISTER/cseq=9911 (tdta0x2340930)! err=70018 (gethostbyname() has
>   returned error (PJ_ERESOLVE))
>
> 02:43:37.421    pjsua_acc.c  .....SIP registration failed, status=502
>   (gethostbyname() has returned error (PJ_ERESOLVE))

looking forward your help.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this is a name resolution problem. The REGISTER URI can not be resolved by your system. Make sure you are pointing to a valid, reachable DNS server or the hostname is configured in your /etc/hosts.

Comment: I know what you mean,but this hostname is the server address  that we want to register in,rather than the localhostname.